# Find the coordinates of the point(s) at which the tangent to the curve is parallel to the x-axis.

Tags: calculus

Find the coordinates of the point(s) at which the tangent to the curve

\begin{equation*}
y=3x^2+5x-7 
\end{equation*}

is parallel to the $x-$axis.

I don't know how to solve this.. help!

Comment: The tangent is parallel to x-axis at the point where $ \frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Comment: Hint: can you find the coordinates of the top of the parabola, even without knowing derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

The slope of the tangent line is the derivative. What is the slope of any line parallel to the $x$-axis?  Can you use these two facts to deduce an answer?